# Save object using HTML 5

Tags: javascript, save, storage, loading

I have trouble getting this local storage to work. It's a small game using javascript. Here is the save and load funtion I'm trying to use.
Is there a better way to do this?
To call the save and load function i am using buttons.

EDIT: I have edited to include the full code.

```js
var snowballs = 0.0;

function userClick(number){
 snowballs = snowballs + number;
 document.getElementById("snowballs").innerHTML = prettify(snowballs);
}

function snowballClick(number){
    snowballs = snowballs + (number* 0.1) ;
    document.getElementById("snowballs").innerHTML = prettify(snowballs);
};

var penguins = 0.0;
var igloos = 0;
function buyPenguin(){
    var penguinCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,penguins));     //works out the cost of this cursor
    if(snowballs >= penguinCost){                                   //checks that the player can afford the cursor
        penguins = penguins + 1;                                   //increases number of cursors
     snowballs = snowballs - penguinCost;                          //removes the cookies spent
        document.getElementById('penguins').innerHTML = penguins;  //updates the number of cursors for the user
        document.getElementById('snowballs').innerHTML = snowballs;  //updates the number of cookies for the user
    };
    var nextCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,penguins));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
    document.getElementById('penguinCost').innerHTML = nextCost;  //updates the cursor cost for the user
};

function save(){
    var save = {
        snowballs: snowballs,
        penguins: penguins,
        igloos: igloos,
        prestige: prestige
 }
 localStorage.setItem("save",JSON.stringify(save));
};

function load(){
    var savegame = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("save"));
    if (typeof savegame.snowballs !== "undefined") snowballs = savegame.snowballs;
    if (typeof savegame.penguins !== "undefined") penguins = savegame.penguins;
    if (typeof savegame.igloos !== "undefined") igloos = savegame.igloos;
    document.getElementById('penguins').innerHTML = penguins;
    document.getElementById('snowballs').innerHTML = snowballs;
    document.getElementById('igloos').innerHTML = igloos;

};

function prettify(input){
    var output = Math.round(input * 1000000)/1000000;
 return output;
}

function buyIgloos(){
    var iglooCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(3,igloos));     //works out the cost of this cursor
    if(snowballs >= iglooCost){                                   //checks that the player can afford the cursor
        igloos = igloos + 1;                                   //increases number of cursors
     snowballs = snowballs - iglooCost;                          //removes the cookies spent
        document.getElementById('penguins').innerHTML = penguins;  //updates the number of cursors for the user
        document.getElementById('snowballs').innerHTML = snowballs;  //updates the number of cookies for the user
        document.getElementById('igloos').innerHTML = igloos;
    };
    var nextIglooCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(3,igloos));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
    document.getElementById('iglooCost').innerHTML = nextIglooCost;  //updates the cursor cost for the user
};

















function devGive(){
 snowballs = snowballs + 100
 document.getElementById("snowballs").innerHTML = prettify(snowballs);
}




window.setInterval(function(){
 
 snowballClick(penguins);
 userClick(igloos)
  
}, 1000);
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="interface.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <button onclick="userClick(1)">Click Me!</button>
  <br />
  Snowballs: <span id="snowballs">0</span>
  <br />
  <button onclick="buyPenguin()">Buy Penguin</button>
  <br />
  Penguins: <span id="penguins">0</span>
  <br />
  Penguin Cost: <span id="penguinCost">10</span>
  <br />
  <button onclick="save()">Save!</button>
  <br />
  <button onclick="load()">Load!</button>
  <br />
  <button onclick="buyIgloos()">Buy Igloo</button>
  <br />
  Igloos: <span id="igloos">0</span>
  <br />
  Igloo Cost: <span id="iglooCost">10</span>
  <button onclick="devGive()">dev give 100</button>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your code working at all? Object is saved and loaded successfully?

Comment: Hi there, Yes everything works all good except for the save and load functions. When i attempt to call the save or load function nothing happens at all... I'm unsure what the problem is, I have followed the instructions on http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp.

I appreciate any advice, Thanks.

Comment: So is there some kind of error? From your code I would say that saving/loading should work.

Comment: I have the console open and i do not get any errors?

here are the buttons I am using maybe they are the problem?

<button onclick="save()">Save!</button>
<br />
<button onclick="load()">Load!</button>
<br />

Comment: I have edited to include the full code if that helps determine the issue, Thanks so much.

Comment: I think you just need to adapt your save object a bit, other than that, your saving and loading in localstorage is good. See my answer and jsfiddle example there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you didn't define prestige variable.

```
var penguins = 0.0;
var igloos = 0;
var snowballs = 0.0;
var prestige = 'prestige'

function save(){
    var save = {
        snowballs: snowballs,
        penguins: penguins,
        igloos: igloos,
        prestige: prestige
    }
    localStorage.setItem("save",JSON.stringify(save));
};
```

See this link, it will work: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Lh7ajqk/16/)

Comment: ok thanks i am still learning so i appreciate the help :P

I have copied your html code into my html page and the js aswell, now it seems it autoloads when i refresh but straight away the value goes to "nan"? any ideas?

Comment: I have updated my anaswer, check it out, and check jsfiddle link again too. If this solves your issue be sure to mark it as answer.

Comment: Oh god just deleted the prestige bit and it worked with original code... silly me i was planning on adding that next but when it didn't work i spent the last hr debugging and trying to make it save... haha Thanks!!

Comment: Or you could just declare that prestige variable and it would work too. Anyways, I'm glad I helped.